# create TextArea dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create one class which extends EditText and in that i pass height,width,textsize,xposition,yposition from json file.
Now , i don't know how to set its background color.I also want to create border if in JSON file there are only two parameter of lefttop and rightbottom then rest of two parameter by default taken as 0 and draw border. .please help me.

Here is my code..

```
public EditText createEditText() throws JSONException
{
    editText = new EditText(mContext);

    LayoutParams layoutParams=new LayoutParams(convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("width")),convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("height")));
    layoutParams.setMargins(convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("xposition")),convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("yposition")), 0, 0);

    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);        
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    try
    {
        if(jsonObject.has("tips"))
        {
            editText.setHint(jsonObject.getString("tips"));
        }
        else{
            editText.setHint("Enter Text");
        }

        if(jsonObject.has("textsize")){
            editText.setTextSize(jsonObject.getInt("textsize"));
        }else{
            editText.setTextSize(14);
        }

        if(jsonObject.has("textcolor")){
            editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(jsonObject.getString("textcolor")));
        }else
        {
            editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if(jsonObject.has("topleftR") && jsonObject.has("toprightR") && jsonObject.has("bottomleftR") && jsonObject.has("bottomrightR"))
        {
            //  top-left,top-right,bottom-right,bottom-left
            int topleftR = convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("topleftR"));
            int toprightR=convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("toprightR"));
            int bottomleftR =convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("bottomleftR"));
            int bottomrightR =convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("bottomrightR"));
            ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(new float[]{
                    topleftR,topleftR,toprightR,toprightR,
                    bottomrightR,bottomrightR,bottomleftR,bottomleftR},
                    null, null)); 

            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(jsonObject.getString("bordercolor")));
            mDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(convertToPixel(3));
            mDrawable.setBounds(convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("xposition")),convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("yposition")), 
                    convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("xposition")) + convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("width")), 
                    convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("yposition")) + convertToPixel(jsonObject.getInt("height")));   
            editText.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
        }
        else
        {
            editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){}

    //editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    return editText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use EditText?Anyway, you can set your background like this:

```
editText.setBackground(R.drawable.your_image_here);
```

Now, if you getting successfully the json object , then

```
try{
String leftTop = jsonObject.getString("leftTopR");
String rightBottom = jsonObject.getString("rightBottomR");
} catch (JSONException e){
e.printtackTrace;
}

if (leftTop.equalsIgnoreCase("0") && rightBottom.equalsIgnoreCase("0"){
//// draw your border here 
}
```

Comment: thanx... I want to create textarea programatically based on JSON data that's why i used edittext as a super class ..i want whole data from json not from resource folder so R,drawable.your_image is not that much useful in my case...

Comment: Why dont you use just text instead of text?i think that you are a bit confused dude.i cant see ths relation between background image and json.!